# My div has a weird set width and i cant change it

Tags: html, css

so basicly i have a div that just goes crazy with its width. The div contains a photo and some text that i cant reveal, but just know it is there. I want the whole div to be as wide as the picture is, but as you can see on the photo it doesnt do that. It is also colored, so that is why its so big on an issue. There are also going to be 4 of these "cells" on the page, so they have to have display: flex; but if i try that the divs next to each other just go crazy. Please help me with this width issue, Thanks!
**HTML:**

```
            <h1>Secretariat</h1>
            <div class="matej">
                <img src="imgs/team_matej.jpg" alt="Photo of Matej Marek">
                <!--other stuff (secret)-->
            </div>
```

**SCSS Later converted to CSS:**

```
        h1{
            font-family: "futura-bold";
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 250%;
        }
        .matej{
            background-color: #0e1a45;
            img{
                width: 10%;
            }
        }
```

**Picture:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried display inline-block for example?

Comment: what is crazy about the width? looks 100% like a block element is going to do.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `div`s are block-level. If you want to contain its width around its content, then you can change its `display` property to be `inline-block`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display for more info.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "futura-bold";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 250%;
}

.matej {
  background-color: #0e1a45;
  display: inline-block;
}

.magej img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Secretariat</h1>
<div class="matej">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/491/200/300.jpg?hmac=1uGno3XFc0HqGY5bM9-mMu0M_wwx7oC0bC1hj_a9p04" alt="Photo of Matej Marek">
</div>
```